# Telegram-bot sensor data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot, sensors, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to write simple telegram bot which returns temperature or humidity values from sensor installed on raspberry pi. The problem is that I'm getting constant velue for temp and hum all the time. Basically loop is not working and bot do not read new values for temp and hum.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
import bme680 # sensor lib
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

sensor = bme680.BME680()
sensor.set_humidity_oversample(bme680.OS_2X)
sensor.set_pressure_oversample(bme680.OS_4X)
sensor.set_temperature_oversample(bme680.OS_8X)
sensor.set_filter(bme680.FILTER_SIZE_3)

def temp():
    temp = sensor.data.temperature
    return temp

def hum():
    hum = sensor.data.humidity
    return hum

while True:
    if sensor.get_sensor_data():
    
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def start_message(message):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi! Temp or Hum?')
                        
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def send_text(message):
            if message.text == 'Temp':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Temp ' + str(temp()))
            elif message.text == 'Hum':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hum '+str(hum()))
                
        bot.polling()
```

Comment: Would you please include the output as well so that we may see what you're getting. In addition would you please include the specific sensor data ... is this Adafruit sensor? Thanks! (https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/bme680/en/latest/)

Comment: I have the slight impression that sensor.get_sensor_data() gets the data from the device and stores its value in data, so every time you call hum() and temp() you recover what is already stored in data but you never refresh its value. I would try calling get_sensor_data() before calling humidity or temperature

Comment: @SergioR you were absolutely right, adding "if sensor.get_sensor_data():" in the beginning of each function worked perfectly well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sensor.get_sensor_data() gets the data from the device and stores its value in data and this value never refreshes.
The solution is to put sensor.get_sensor_data() at he beginning of Temp and Hum functions:

```
def temp():
    if sensor.get_sensor_data():
        temp = sensor.data.temperature
        return temp

def hum():
    if sensor.get_sensor_data():
        hum = sensor.data.humidity
        return hum
```